# How to utilize data stored in a multidimensional array

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array

How do I display the multiple data's I stored in a multidimensional array in Java (eclipse)? I need to output the sweets recorded at each location and I am not sure how to go about that. The user needs to first input the sweet with the price at each location. After they have done all the inputs, there is supposed to be a menu outputted with the sweets they inputted at a specific location. What I do not understand is how to display the arrays which have stored the sweets inputted.
*My code can be displayed below*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DessertExplosion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        //Declare Variables
        String dessert[][][]=new String[3][3][2];
        double price[]=new double[18];
        int counter=0;
        String locationMenu="";
        //Print menu statement
        System.out.println("DESSERT EXPLOSION DAILY MENU ENTRY");
        //Use for loop to determine dessert types and prices
        for(int x=0;x<dessert.length;x++) {
            for(int n=0;n<dessert[x].length;n++) {
                for(int i=0;i<dessert[x][n].length;i++) {
                    counter++;
                    //Oshawa location
                    if (counter==1) {
                        System.out.println("---Oshawa---");
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cakes
                        System.out.println("Category: Cake");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cookies
                        System.out.println("Category: Cookie");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Ice Cream
                        System.out.println("Category: Ice Crea,");
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                    }
                    //Whitby Location
                    else if(counter==2) {
                        System.out.println("---Whitby---");
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cakes
                        System.out.println("Category: Cake");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cookies
                        System.out.println("Category: Cookie");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Ice Cream
                        System.out.println("Category: Ice Crea,");
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                    }
                    //Ajax location
                    else if(counter==3){
                        System.out.println("---Ajax---");
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cakes
                        System.out.println("Category: Cake");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cake item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cake $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Cookies
                        System.out.println("Category: Cookie");
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Cookie item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " cookie $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("------------------------------");
                        //Ice Cream
                        System.out.println("Category: Ice Cream");
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #1");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.println("Enter Ice Cream item #2");
                        dessert[x][n][i]=input.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter price for " + dessert[x][n][i] + " Ice Cream $");
                        price[i]=input.nextDouble();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to do basically the same, which is using for loops going through your multidimensional array, retrieving each element with the indices of the loops then printing them out. You can use a space between each dessert printed to output the whole content. Since it's a 3 dimensional array, its display will depend on how you want to do it.

Personally, I'd display it as if it was a 2d array but the elements (in the 3rd array) are shown directly as arrays like this.

```
Arrays.toString(desserts[x][n])
```

But it depends on you.

Comment: Okay Thank You so much